# Can't understand why this doesn't satisfy Laman's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laman_graph

The following graph (top of picture) has $12$ vertices and $2\cdot12-3 = 21$ edges. I've tested all $2^{12}$ subsets of vertices, and all subgraphs formed satisfy $e \leq 2v^*-3$.

However, it is clearly not rigid, as the bottom transformation shows.

What am I missing?

[image: Counterexample]

Comment: The points in your graph are not in general position; for instance, you have many cases where $\ge 3$ points are collinear.  If you distort the graph a bit (e.g., by making the right-hand squares a bit larger than the left-hand squares), it becomes rigid.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: The condition on the number of edges is necessary but not sufficient. The fact you can exhibit a transformation to the fact that $G$ is not rigid is enough.